# Execution time for CONTAINSTABLE/WHERE query

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I am facing an issue for a seemingly trivial database query on SQL Server 2012 accessing a full-text index:

```
SELECT MyTable.ID FROM MyTable INNER JOIN (
  SELECT [KEY] FROM CONTAINSTABLE(MyTable,FullText,'"ab*"',10)
  UNION ALL SELECT 1
) T ON T.[KEY]=MyTable.ID
WHERE ForeignKey=123
```

The query takes multiple seconds to return no results. If either the `UNION` or the `WHERE` clause is removed the query completes instantaneously. Also the performance varies when changing the `ForeignKey` value.

My assumption is that SQL Server executes the query in an inefficient way but I don't know what to do about that.

**UPDATE**

Execution plans generated with `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON`

Full query:

```
|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyTable].[ID]))
   |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyTable].[IX_ForeignKey]), SEEK:([MyTable].[ForeignKey]=(123)) ORDERED FORWARD)
   |--Concatenation
        |--Filter(WHERE:([MyTable].[ID]=FulltextMatch.[docid]))
        |    |--Sort(TOP 10, ORDER BY:(FulltextMatch.[score] DESC, FulltextMatch.[docid] ASC))
        |         |--Table-valued function
        |--Filter(WHERE:(STARTUP EXPR([MyTable].[ID]=(1))))
             |--Filter(WHERE:([MyTable].[ID]=[Expr1003]))
                  |--Constant Scan(VALUES:(((1))))
```

Without `WHERE ForeignKey=123`:

```
|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Union1004]))
   |--Concatenation
   |    |--Sort(TOP 10, ORDER BY:(FulltextMatch.[score] DESC, FulltextMatch.[docid] ASC))
   |    |    |--Table-valued function
   |    |--Constant Scan(VALUES:(((1))))
   |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyTable].[IX_ID_WithForeignKeyColumn]), SEEK:([MyTable].[ID]=[Union1004]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Without `UNION ALL SELECT 1`:

```
|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:(FulltextMatch.[docid]))
   |--Sort(TOP 10, ORDER BY:(FulltextMatch.[score] DESC, FulltextMatch.[docid] ASC))
   |    |--Table-valued function
   |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyTable].[IX_ForeignKey]), SEEK:([MyTable].[ForeignKey]=(123) AND [MyTable].[ID]=FulltextMatch.[docid]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your select 1? Can't you move it away from the there?

Comment: It used to be another CONTAINSTABLE statement potentially with other SELECTs following. I replaced it with SELECT 1 to arrive at a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You should include query plans from the different cases, that usually helps understanding optimization problems.

Comment: I have used `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT` to generate plans, hope I managed to capture helpful information.

Comment: I'd like to understand the downvote which means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". What's the specific problem with the question?

Comment: Even if the question would be new, that 1 person might not get the notification. Asking that 2.5 years later, it's really kind of a long shot.

Comment: The vote was cast a few days ago so I thought I might get an answer. Always happy to learn :-)